# Problema con Socialite Google en Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, socialite

Tenía funcionando correctamente la autentificación por Google y de repente me empezó a dar el siguiente error en Producción (En localhost todo sigue funcionando normal). Busque mucho antes de llegar a realizar esta consulta y probé todas las opciones que hay en la web y no doy con la solución.

El error: Debug

Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en LoginController me marca error en la siguiente linea:

```
  $userSocialite = Socialite::driver($driver)->user();
```

En el Log del servidor:

> local.ERROR:  {"exception":"[object] (Laravel\Socialite\Two\InvalidStateException(code: 0):  at /home/brooklyn/Sistema/vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/AbstractProvider.php:209)
> [stacktrace]

Mi LoginController:

```
//Socialite
public function redirectToProvider($driver)
{
    $drivers = ['google'];

    if(in_array($driver, $drivers)){

        return Socialite::driver($driver)->redirect();

    }else{
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('info', $driver . ' no es una aplicación valida para poder loguearse');
    }

}

public function handleProviderCallback(Request $request, $driver)
{
    if($request->get('error')){
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('info', 'Ocurrió un error, vuelva a intentarlo más tarde.');
    }

    $userSocialite = Socialite::driver($driver)->user();


    $social_profile = SocialProfile::where('social_id', $userSocialite->getId())
                                   ->where('social_name', $driver)->first();

    if(!$social_profile){

        $user = User::where('email', $userSocialite->getEmail())->first();
        if(!$user){
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $userSocialite->user['given_name'],
                'apellido' => $userSocialite->user['family_name'],
                'email' => $userSocialite->getEmail(),
                'permiso' => 'USUARIO',
                'tipo_usuario' => 'PARTICULAR'
            ]);
        }

        SocialProfile::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'social_id' => $userSocialite->getId(),
            'social_name' => $driver,
            'social_avatar' => $userSocialite->getAvatar()
        ]);

    }

    auth()->login($social_profile->user);

    return redirect()->route('panel');

    /* dd($user->user['given_name']); */

    // $user->token;
}
```

**PRUEBAS REALIZADAS SIN EFECTO**

**1 PRUEBA**

En Localhost si realizo la siguiente modificación:

En **session.php**

Cambio esto:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

A:

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'midominio.com'),
```

En Local recibo el mismo error que producción. Y en producción el error persiste.

**2 PRUEBA**

Agregar a LoginController

```
Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();
```

Recibo el siguiente error:

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException
> Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code" }

**NUEVAS PRUEBAS**

Cree con otra cuenta de gmail todo el Auth y el error persiste.

También elimine todo el proyecto en el servidor y cree una nueva cuenta y no sirvió.

Comment: Revisaste tu .env para verificar tus credenciales? O dónde tienes tus credenciales?

Comment: Buenas!! si lo tengo en el archivo .ENV. Verifique que esté todo bien ahí. Antes me funcionaba bien. Tuve que subir varias modificaciones y me dejo de andar. La modificación que subí es un middleware. Ahora lo que probé es crear con otra cuenta gmail un nuevo Auth y recibo el mismo problema.

Comment: Qué servidor estás utilizando? Apache o Nginx

Comment: Apache. La verdad estoy desconcertado

Comment: ¿Usas un software de control de versiones como Git? Si es así, te recomiendo regresar a la versión de antes de integrar el middleware que mencionas, luego volver a integrarlo probando paso por paso para saber en qué punto se rompe.

Comment: Ya has configurado un dominio en apache anteriormente? Verifica que tu dominio esté habilitado y bien configurado en sites-enabled

Comment: Hola @BaruchSpinoza si uso Git pero nunca tuve que volver el estado de un proyecto a uno anterior por lo tanto voy a ver como hacerlo y probar por que antes me funcionaba bien, tiene que ser algo nuevo de lo que agregué el problema.

Comment: No olvides limpiar la caché y hacer un dump-autoload

Comment: Buenas... Volví con Git a un estado que antes funcionaba y tengo el mismo problema. Elimine el servidor y cree uno nuevo y persiste el problema. En localhost haga lo que haga funciona todo perfecto. ¿Hay algo que pueda verificar en el servidor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de varios días luchando con esto lo pude solucionar agregando el siguiente código:

```
if (empty($_GET)) {
        $t = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($t, $output);
        foreach ($output as $key => $value) {
            $request->query->set($key, $value);
        }
    }

    $userSocialite = Socialite::driver($driver)->user();
```

Nosé si será la mejor solución, pero es la única que encontré.

También en mi caso tenía un problema en la siguiente parte: detectado por @L.Flor, Gracias

```
**$social_profile =** SocialProfile::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'social_id' => $userSocialite->getId(),
        'social_name' => $driver,
        'social_avatar' => $userSocialite->getAvatar()
    ]);
```