# Google quiebre de seguridad

Tags: google-chrome

Tengo un  formulario realizado con Blade, que tomo los datos con un form a través del request en Laravel 7.

```
 <form class="user" method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                                    @csrf

                                   

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="name" type="name" class="form-control form-control-user @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre">
                                        @error('name')<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $message }}</strong></span> @enderror
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="apellido" type="apellido" class="form-control form-control-user @error('apellido') is-invalid @enderror" name="apellido" value="{{ old('apellido') }}" required autocomplete="apellido" placeholder="Ingrese su apellido">
                                        @error('apellido')<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $message }}</strong></span> @enderror
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="celular" type="celular" class="form-control form-control-user @error('celular') is-invalid @enderror" name="celular" value="{{ old('celular') }}" required autocomplete="celular" placeholder="Ingrese su celular">
                                        @error('celular')<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $message }}</strong></span> @enderror
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="documento" type="documento" class="form-control form-control-user @error('documento') is-invalid @enderror" name="documento" value="{{ old('documento') }}" required autocomplete="documento" autofocus aria-describedby="documentoHelp" placeholder="Ingrese documento de identidad">
                                        @error('documento')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong></span> @enderror
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control form-control-user @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email" autofocus aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Ingrese su email">
                                        @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong></span> @enderror
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control form-control-user form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Contraseña">
                                        @error('password')<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $message }}</strong></span> @enderror
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" name="password_confirmation" class="form-control form-control-user form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" required autocomplete="current-password" placeholder="Repetir Contraseña">
                                        @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>{{ $message }}</strong></span> @enderror
                                    </div>

                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">
                                        Registrarse
                                    </button>

                                    <hr> @if(session('info'))
                                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                                        <b>{{session('info')}}</b>
                                    </div>
                                    @endif

                                    <a href="{{ url('login/google') }}" class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">
                                        <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Acceder con Google
                                    </a>

                                </form>
```

Y Google me marca el siguiente mensaje a su vez estoy teniendo un problema con Google Socialite que creo que puede llegar a estar asociado.

[Problema con Socialite](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/398913/problema-con-socialite-google-en-laravel-7)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el insert utilizo el create del Auth por defecto.

Que puedo hacer para solucionar este inconveniente?

Comment: Seria interesante saber mas del "quiebre de seguridad" por que es demasiado amplio, aca dice que hasta una extension pòdria causar esto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen bases de datos públicas que contienen contraseñas que se sabe han estado expuestas en alguna brecha de seguridad ocurrida en el pasado.

Por ejemplo: https://haveibeenpwned.com/Passwords

Google Chrome consulta estas base de datos cuando un usuario introduce datos en un formulario con un campo de tipo `password`.

Por ende, si estás introduciendo alguna contraseña que haya estado comprometida, saltará esta alerta de seguridad.

Al igual que Google Chrome, el sitio haveibeenpwned.com también ofrece la posibilidad de consultar contraseñas vulneradas, por ejemplo, si consulto la contraseña `usuario123` me dice que esta contraseña ya ha aparecido en bases de datos extraídas clandestinamente (Comúnmente se dice que han sido hackeadas).

Comment: Tal cuál, estaba haciendo pruebas poniendo contraseñas de 1234556 muy basicas para hacer rápido y probé poniendo una más segura y ya no sale el mensaje. Muchas gracias

Comment: Para servirte, si consideras que la respuesta fue útil, considera marcarla como aceptada.